# How to use "{" symbol in xaml string

Tags: wpf, xaml

How can I use { symbol in xaml string? E.g.:

```
<TextBlock Text="{0}"/>
```

I can do it starting string with a space symbol:

```
<TextBlock Text=" {0}"/>
```

but I'm looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{}{0}"/>
```

The `{}` at the start tells the parser to not look for markup extensions.

Alternatively, you can specify the data without using an attribute:

```
<TextBlock>{0}</TextBlock>
```